# How do I switch to the next window (NOT the most recent one) in Gnome/Cinnamon?

Tags: gnome, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, cinnamon, window-switching

Let's say that I have 26 open windows in Gnome (specifically, Cinnamon 3.8.8).  I want to efficiently navigate through all of them and perform a single task in each.  How do I accomplish this?  `Alt-Tab` and `Alt-Tick` have the behavior of going to the *previous* window, so if I'm on A and I hit them once then I'm B, but hit them again and I'm on A rather than onto C.  You have to hit them successively more times to get to the later windows, which just doesn't work at all.

Instead, I want to be on window A, press a keyboard shortcut, be on window B, press the shortcut again, be on window C, etc.  In other words, I want to navigate through the windows showing on my desktop taskbar in exactly the way I use `Ctrl-Tab` and `Ctrl-Shift-Tab` to navigate through tabs within an application.

How do I accomplish this?  I'm on Debian, for what it's worth, but I don't think that should affect the answer.

Comment: Are you using GNOME 2 or GNOME 3 desktop?

Comment: Apparently I'm using Cinnamon 3.8.8.  Edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

a little late but it's been a while I was seaching for the same thing as you, and sometime ago saw I wasn't alone when I found your question. I didn't find any way to do that on Cinnamon, so I coded it myself.

There is this PR which make some preparations for this functionality
https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/pull/10490#issuecomment-988231077

And the full code is here: https://github.com/alefpereira/cinnamon/tree/gwl-add-hotkey-to-cycle-apps

It's not integrated yet, but I hope they'll accept this change soon.

[image: Cycle App Forward/Backward hotkeys]